# Javascript - how to get an element by ID and name?

Tags: javascript

This is how I detect an element by its ID:

```
var address = document.getElementById('address');
```

However, I'd want to specify that I want to detect only element with this ID (`address`) AND that the element is `input`, nothing else (eg. `select`).

So `input#address` would be picked up, but `select#address` would be ignored.

How do I do that?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you aware that the purpose of an `id` is to be unique? So having two elements with `id="address"` would defeat the purpose of using ids. Consider using `class` instead.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors/Type_Class_and_ID_Selectors#id_selectors

Answer (score 2):

You can actually do exactly that with querySelector:

```js
const address = document.querySelector('input#address')
```

Answer (score 1):

`document.querySelector("input#address")`